# for loop only stores last value

Tags: r, loops

I wrote a for loop in `R` and try to store my computed values in a matrix. Unfortunately, it only saves my last value. I already browsed the internet and I found out, this problem can be solved by indexing. However, I already do that and it still doesn't work. Do you see my mistake?

Data set:

```
require(stats)

data <- ts.union(a=arima.sim(model=list(ar=c(.9,-.2)), n=144), 
             b=arima.sim(model=list(ar=c(.6, -.3)), n=144), 
             c=arima.sim(model=list(ar=c(-.2,-.6)), n=144), 
             d=arima.sim(model=list(ar=c(-.1,-.6)), n=144), 
             e=arima.sim(model=list(ar=c(.2,-.6)), n=144), 
             f=arima.sim(model=list(ar=c(.2,.7)), n=144), 
             g=arima.sim(model=list(ar=c(.3,.2)), n=144), 
             h=arima.sim(model=list(ar=c(-.4,.3)), n=144), 
             i=arima.sim(model=list(ar=c(.1,-.7)), n=144), 
             j=arima.sim(model=list(ar=c(.8,.1)), n=144))
data <- ts(data, start=c(2007, 2), frequency=12)
```

loop:

```
require(vars)

for(i in 1:12){
  # compute factors, window is 5.5 years wide
  factors <- ts(prcomp(window(data, start=c(2007, (i+1)), end=c(2012, i+6)), center=T, scale=T)$x[,1:5], 
          start=c(2007,(i+1)), frequency=12)
  # estimate VAR model
  model <- VAR(window(data, start=c(2007, (i+1)), end=c(2012, i+6)), 
         exogen=factors, type="const")
  # forecast factors
  factor.fcst <- sapply(factors, function(x) predict(auto.arima(x, stationary=T, seasonal=F), n.ahead=12))[1,]
  factor.fcst <- cbind(factor.fcst$PC1, factor.fcst$PC2, factor.fcst$PC3, factor.fcst$PC4, factor.fcst$PC5)
  colnames(factor.fcst) <- colnames(factors)

  # forecast model
  a_fcst <- ts(predict(model, dumvar=factor.fcst, n.ahead=12, ci=0.95)$fcst$a[,1],
              start=c(2012, (i+7)), frequency=12)
  # compute RMSE
  RMSE <- matrix(ncol=1, nrow=12)
  RMSE[i,] <- sqrt(mean((window(data[,1], start=c(2012, (i+7)), 
                          end=c(2012, (i+18))) - a_fcst)^2))
  print(RMSE)
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are resetting RMSE every iteration with `RMSE <- matrix(ncol=1, nrow=12)`, take that out of the loop. In general, you should try to avoid loops - have a look at the `rollapply` function in the `zoo` package for ways to do timeseries analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simpler example:

```
  d1 <- seq(10)
  ans1 <- vector(length=length(d1), mode="double")
  for (i in seq.int(length(d1))){
    ans1[i] <- sqrt(d1[i])
  }
```

Now, if we take the second line and put it inside the loop, only the last value is returned i.e. the value of `ans1` is reset each time the loop is run.

This sort of code is far from 'best practice'. That said, loops can often be a useful first step towards vectorizing a function, can be easier to read and (rarely) can be faster.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I haven't seen that.